# re parametrizing a sphere to have constant "length"?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, arc-length

A unit sphere can be parametrized as:

$$\vec r(u,v)=\langle\cos(u)\sin(v), \sin(u)\sin(v), \cos(v)\rangle$$

Now if one wishes to study the arclength accross the meridians and the parallels we get that, for the meridians the rate of change of the length is:

$$\left|\vec{r'_{m}}\right| = 1$$

The rate of change with respect to $v$ of the arclength of a meridian is 1, so there is no "deformation" along a meridian, or meridians form arclength parametrized curves. (I didn't go into the details, you can verify this if you want)

However let's study the parallels now, a parallel can be thought as a curve of one variable if we hold $v$ constant, and so we get:

$$\begin{align}x'&=-\sin(u)\sin(v) \\
y' & =\cos(u)\sin(v)\\
z' & =0\end{align}$$

So we get that the arclength becomes:

$$\int^u_0 \sqrt{\sin^2(u)\sin^2(v)+\cos^2(u)\sin^2(v)}\,du$$
$$=\int^u_0\sin(v)du$$
$$=u\sin(v)$$

So we get: $S=u\sin(v)\iff u=\frac{S}{\sin(v)}$

The re-parametrization of one of these curves should thus be:

$\vec r_v(u)=\left\langle\cos\left(\frac{u}{\sin(v)}\right)\sin(v), \sin\left(\frac{u}{\sin(v)}\right)\sin(v), \cos(v)\right\rangle$

Now we obviously get a huge instability near the poles where $\sin(v)=0$ but we will ignore them for now and focus exclusively on the regions of the Sphere were this new parametrization is well defined.

Consider the original parametrization of a sphere. In this case if one projects a straight line onto the sphere there is a deformation appearing from the fact that the parallels are "squished":

[image]

By straigth line we mean, take 2 points $P_1, P_2$ such that their coordinates are within the correct ranges for $(u,v)$ and linearly interpolate between the 2 (i.e $(1-t)P_1 + tP_2$).

The new parametrization however, should have corrected this deformation, and so we should see something close to a geodesic. However this is what I am observing:

[image]

Could anybody explain to me where on my analysis I went wrong, and ideally, how to correct this deformation?

Comment: Why don't you try plotting the lines of constant $u$ and $v$ for your new parametrization and see what they look like?

Comment: Because no matter what the parametrization is, holding u and v constant always generates meridians and parallels, so you cannot tell a difference in between the parametrizations.

Comment: That's where you're wrong, I'm afraid. Your lines of constant $u$ are no longer meridians.

Comment: Huh, you seem to be correct, why is that?

Comment: Because you have changed the parametrization. The parametrization determines the isolines and vice versa, so I don't know why you expect to be able to change one without changing the other.

Comment: Ignorance i guess, and a lack of foresight. But this preocupies me, since I need to find a way to correct this deformation without appealing to geodesics.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If "correcting the deformation" means something strong enough then it might be impossible thanks to the [Theorema Egregium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium). Since you seem concerned with coordinate lines being geodesics, perhaps you'll be interested in the [Gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection).

Comment: I am trying to find a way to map at least a hemisphere into a 2D space in any coordinate system (polar or cartesian), such that I can project a straight line from the 2D representation into the 3D representation and whatever comes out is not "deformed" deformed here is loose because all we care about is the visual aspect of it, not the analytic validity of the shape.

So I just want to get a "straight" line after projecting (in the case of a sphere this'll look like a geodesic or close enough)

Answer (score 1):

If you could reparametrize any open subset of a sphere so that the coordinate vector fields have constant length, then that open subset would be flat (zero curvature). But, as we can see in various ways, the sphere has constant positive curvature.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what you are asking. Maybe you just haven't sorted out the variables correctly. At any rate, if
$${\bf r}(u,v):=\bigl(\cos u\sin v,\sin u\sin v,\cos v\bigr)$$
is the chosen parametrization of the sphere then the latitude circles $\ell_v$ are parametrized by
$$\ell_v: \quad u\mapsto {\rm p}(u):=\bigl(\cos u\sin v,\sin u\sin v,\cos v\bigr)\qquad(0\leq u\leq 2\pi)$$
(same as above, but only $u$ is variable here). The arc length $u\mapsto s(u)$ along $\ell_v$ comes to $$s(u)=\sin v\>u\ ,$$
hence $u={s\over \sin v}$. Introducing $s$ as parameter along $\ell_v$ means considering the new vector valued function $${\bf q}(s):={\bf p}\left({s\over\sin v}\right)=\left(\cos {s\over\sin v}\>\sin v,\ \sin {s\over\sin v}\>\sin v,\ \cos v\right)\qquad(0\leq s\leq 2\pi\sin v)\ .$$
One computes
$${\bf q}'(s)=\left(-\sin {s\over\sin v},\ \cos {s\over\sin v},\ 0 \right)\ ,$$
which is a unit vector parallel to the $(x,y)$-plane, as expected.